# Custom ListView using ArrayAdapter, OnClick event

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a Custom ListView using Arrayadapter that has a portion of the view for handling the onClick event. I've set it in the code below. when the user clicks the view it will pull up a youtube video. What I need to know how to do is have a different video play for each individual view click. Here is my code

```
 public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {

Context context;
private static final String[] videoId = {"-Uwjt32NvVA", "J7-8IteUvt8", "XjwZAa2EjKA",};

public CustomList(Context context, int resourceId,
        List<RowItem> items) {
    super(context, resourceId, items);
    this.context = context;
}

/*private view holder class*/
private class ViewHolder {
   // ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtCareer;
    TextView txtSeason;
    TextView txtGame;
    RelativeLayout highlight;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.txtCareer = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.career);
        holder.txtSeason = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.season);
        holder.txtGame = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.game);
        holder.highlight = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.highlight);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
    holder.txtCareer.setText(rowItem.getCareer());
    holder.txtSeason.setText(rowItem.getSeason());
    holder.txtGame.setText(rowItem.getGame());
    //holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.geturl());

    holder.highlight .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,  Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:"+videoId)); 
            intent.putExtra("VIDEO_ID", videoId); 
            context.startActivity(intent); 

        }
    });

    return convertView;
}


}
```

Everything works I just am not sure how to get a different video to play when the user selects a different view in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,  Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:"+videoId[position])); 
 intent.putExtra("VIDEO_ID", videoId[position]); 
 context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Dang so Simple. Thanks so much this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

```
ss=(String) ((TextView) view).getText();

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,  Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:"+ss)); 
context.startActivity(intent);
```